# What is this multi-winner voting problem related to? Load balancing? Quadratic Constraint? Integer optimization? Gurobi solves it? Can it go faster?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming, voting-theory, mixed-integer-programming

**Problem Statement**

Let's run an election.

$i \in \text{voters}$

$j \in \text{candidates}$

$x_j \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ The candidate is chosen by setting this to 1.  This is the election result.

$b_{i,j} \in [0,1]$ Ballot of voter i for candidate j.  Voter gives bigger numbers if he likes the candidate.  This is the input to the election.

Now, how do we choose $x_j$ so that the best group of candidates win?  Here is one optimization.

**edit 2**: Actually this is a better problem.

> Maximize $Z$ subject to
>
> $\begin{array}{ll}
> \forall _{j } , & \sum_{i}  f_i * b_{ij}^2 * x_j \geq Z * x_j   & \text{ Minimum winning score is maximized.} \\ 
>  \forall _{i } , & \sum_{j}  f_i * b_{ij} * x_j = 1 & \text{The weight of each voter is the same.}  \leq \text{works too}\\
>   & \sum_{j } x_j = N & \text{ The number of seats is N.}
> \end{array}
> $
>   When I try this in Gurobi, it complains, "Q matrix is not positive semi-definite".  However, I can set an upper bound on f and then it will work.  Also, I can linearize something:
>
> $ \forall _{j } , \quad N*(x_j-1)+\sum_{i}  f_i * b_{ij}^2  \geq Z \quad    \text{ Minimum winning score is maximized.}  $
>
> Gurobi does solve this, though it takes a lot of time.  I wish I could linearize all the constraints so there is no $f*x$ term.
>
> It is also possible to just say
>
> $\text{Maximize}   \quad {\displaystyle \min_j \sum_i \frac{b_{ij}^2}{\sum_j x_j*b_{ij}}}$
>
> but I'm not sure this helps, though it does get rid of f.

Here's another related problem

> $         \begin{array}{lll}
>         \text{Minimize}   & { \max_{i } \sum_{j } f_i * b_{ij} * x_j} &  \text{The representation of each voter is fair.} \\
>         \text{Subject to} & {\forall \  j } \ \  \sum_{i } f_i * b_{ij}^2 *x_j \geq x_j \ \ \  & \text{The value of each winning seat is the same.} 
>         \end{array} $

**old stuff below**

**edit 1**: I realize a better problem to solve is this one:

> Maximize $Z$ subject to
>
> $\begin{array}{ll}
> \forall _{j } , & \sum_{i}  f_i * b_{ij} * x_j \geq Z * x_j   & \text{ Minimum winning score is maximized.} \\ 
>  \forall _{i } , & \sum_{j}  f_i * b_{ij} * x_j = 1 & \text{The weight of each voter is the same.}  \leq \text{works too}\\
>   & \sum_{j } x_j = N & \text{ The number of seats is N.}
> \end{array}
> $
>
> When I try this in Gurobi, it complains, "Q matrix is not positive semi-definite".

**The model and explanation below is old but helpful in understanding the problem above.**

> $\begin{array}{ll}
> \text{maximize } \text{ } \text{ }  \sum_{i} & \sum_{j}  f_i * b_{ij} * x_j   \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } &\text{Total score is maximized.} \\ \text{ subject to }  \text{ } \text{ } \forall _{i } , & \sum_{j}  f_i * b_{ij} * x_j \leq 1 & \text{The weight of each voter is the same, basically.}\\
> \text{ and subject to} & \sum_{j } x_j = N & \text{The number of seats is N.}
> \end{array}
> $
>
> What is this $f_i$?  It lets you vote for multiple candidates.  So if two of your candidates that you like end up winning, half your vote went to one and half to the other.  Basically, $f_i$ is a way to divide but using multiplication.
>
> $f_i \in (0,1]$
>
> **How to Help**
>
> I'm glad Gurobi will do this problem.  I was able to implement it.  And it is too slow and I want it to go faster.  I want to know what gurobi is doing.  I have gurobi's log file but it is hard to interpret.  I also have my code.  In the example I am running, I have 216 voters, 10 candidates, and 5 winners.  It takes 42 seconds.
>
> What is this problem related to and are there different forms to implement it?
>
> It is a kind of load balancing where the loading is factorized to $f_i * x_j$ instead of $x_{i,j}$.  It is a binary problem in $x_j$ and it is also continuous in $f_i$.  This is a committee selection problem.  It's also almost a binary quadratic problem except it has this additional $f_i$, which is continuous.
>
> There could be a simplification of $f_i$ because it is either 1 or $\frac{1}{\sum_{j} b_{ij} * x_j}$.  Maybe this quadratic constraint can be simplified.